# How Money is deducted from bank account for bill payment of WhatsApp cloud API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, whatsapp, whatsapi, whatsapp-cloud-api

recently I have setup WhatsApp cloud API with payment option but I don't have any idea how WhatsApp going to deduct money ( for messages I will send ) from my bank account. is it deduct automatically from bank account on monthly basis since I give my debit card information or I have to do manually payment by visiting WhatsApp cloud API website. I have searched on the web but cant find answer please help